# Compare list items to $scope variables

Tags: javascript, html, image, function

I am new to javascript and am having a hard time using it to manipulate my html elements.

Right now I have an array of images in my javascript file.

I am trying to only display the id of my img if it matches the nav bar's list item.

Here is my javascript file :

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module('myContent',[]);

app.controller('ContentController',function($scope) {

    $scope.img=[
                 {id:'TOPS',source:'images/top1.jpg'},
                 {id:'TOPS',source:'images/top2.jpg'},
                 {id:'TOPS',source:'images/top3.jpg'},
                 {id:'TOPS',source:'images/top4.jpg'},
                 {id:'SHOES',source:'images/shoe1.jpg'},
                 {id:'SHOES',source:'images/shoe2.jpg'},
                 {id:'SHOES',source:'images/shoe3.jpg'},
                 {id:'SHOES',source:'images/shoe4.jpg'}
    ];

});

})();
```

Here is my html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myContent">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>ShopME Tops</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-
 awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js
"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<header>

<div class="header-inner2">
    <nav>
        <ul class="center">
            <li><a href="tops.html">SWIMWEAR</a></li>
            <li><a href="tops.html">TOPS</a></li>
            <li><a href="tops.html">BOTTOMS</a></li>
            <li><a href="tops.html">DRESSES</a></li>
            <li><a href="tops.html">SHOES</a></li>
            <li><a href="tops.html">ACCESSORIES</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
</div>
</header>


<!-- Container for grid layout -->
<div class="container" ng-controller="ContentController">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" ng-repeat="x in img">
            <a ng-href="{{x.link}}" target="_blank">
            <img class="img-responsive1" ng-src="{{x.source}}" alt="#">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there anyway to compare the list item to the img.id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the value to a function and use filter to filter the values,like below

```
 $scope.getData = function(value){
    $scope.filtered = $scope.img.filter(test=>test.id == value);
 }
```

**DEMO**

```js
(function() {

var app = angular.module('myContent',[]);

app.controller('ContentController',function($scope) {
    $scope.filteted = [];
    $scope.img=[
                 {id:'TOPS',source:'images/top1.jpg'},
                 {id:'TOPS',source:'images/top2.jpg'},
                 {id:'TOPS',source:'images/top3.jpg'},
                 {id:'TOPS',source:'images/top4.jpg'},
                 {id:'SHOES',source:'images/shoe1.jpg'},
                 {id:'SHOES',source:'images/shoe2.jpg'},
                 {id:'SHOES',source:'images/shoe3.jpg'},
                 {id:'SHOES',source:'images/shoe4.jpg'}
    ];
    $scope.getData = function(value){
      $scope.filtered = $scope.img.filter(test=>test.id == value);
      
    }
});
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myContent">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>ShopME Tops</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-
 awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js
"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div  ng-controller="ContentController" class="header-inner2">
    <nav>
        <ul class="center">
            <li><a ng-click="getData('SWIMWEAR')" >SWIMWEAR</a></li>
            <li><a ng-click="getData('TOPS')">TOPS</a></li>
            <li><a ng-click="getData('BOTTOMS')">BOTTOMS</a></li>
            <li><a ng-click="getData('DRESSES')">DRESSES</a></li>
            <li><a ng-click="getData('SHOES')">SHOES</a></li>
            <li><a ng-click="getData('ACCESSORIES')">ACCESSORIES</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>

 
<!-- Container for grid layout -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" ng-repeat="x in filtered">
            <a ng-href="{{x.link}}" target="_blank">
            <img class="img-responsive1" ng-src="{{x.source}}" alt="#">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what are the test and test.id variables in the javascript file doing?

Comment: test denotes each object inside your array and test.id is to filter the matching id https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: I only ask because I am getting errors saying "test variable implicitly declared" and "expression expected"

Comment: It should not be, check the demo above

Comment: I realized my error, I separated the content in my ng-controller. Thank you @Sajeetharan that worked!!

Comment: Mark as answer if it helped